# Getting Error in making logic of Trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

we have 1:N relationship between Sales_order and Line_item. In the relationship, whenever a new item is inserted into Line_Item table, the “total” attribute of sales_order table needs to be updated. That is. Sales_Order.total =sum(all the line_item.subtotal)

Write a trigger that automatically updates line_item.subtotal value by quantity*actual_price  for INSERT or UPDATE on LINEITEM table.

I am trying to write Trigger Logic but is not working. Check my logic where I am doing mistake...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_subtotals  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON LINE_ITEM 
for each row
DECLARE 
  new_subtotal  number;
BEGIN

  SELECT subtotal INTO new_subtotal FROM LINE_ITEM WHERE order_id = :new.order_id;
  :new.subtotal := :new.quantity * new.actual_price 
END;
/
```

Comment: The error refers to `NEW.SUBTOTALN` which is not mentioned in the code, so are you sure the above version is what you ran? Also the question refers to 'quantity' but the code refers to 'quality'. Please include table creation scripts.

Comment: I updated it Quries.

Comment: A row-level trigger on LINE_ITEM can't query LINE_ITEM, so that's one issue. Then, `actual_price` should probably be `:new.actual_price`, and PL/SQL syntax requires a semicolon after each statement. If you post all the code and scripts needed to reproduce the error, and the full error details, you'll get more detailed replies.

Comment: Actually, with a proper data design, this question wouldn't even arise.  It is a fundamental principle of data design that you do _not_ store and maintain values that can be calculated from other data.  Thus, do not attempt to store a value in SALES_ORDER table when that value is merely the total of values from the subordinate table.  You can and should simply compute that value from the subordinate table at the time you need it.

Comment: You could rather create a view which has an aggregation query containing `quantity * actual_price AS subtotal` column, after reading the above comment of @EdStevens .

Answer (score 0):

Your correct TRIGGER should be -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_subtotals  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON LINE_ITEM 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
       new_subtotal  number;
BEGIN
     UPDATE sales_order
        SET total = total + :new.subtotal
      <YOUR WHERE CONDITION ACCORDINGLY>
END;
/
```

Comment: Please explain why this trigger fixes the problem, rather than just dumping the code in your answer. Please also be aware that your trigger may have problems with null values if the `total` column is nullable, and doesn't correctly handle an `UPDATE` if the line item's subtotal is changed.